# Ruby file_get_contents equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I need to use this in my rails program so I can get the image contents and then base64 it. I know how to base64 it but I just don't know how I would get the image. Anyone know how?

Comment: After you got site content you can try to parse it using regular expression. Also you can take a look to [nokogiri](http://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri) gem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edited to retrieve from external URL:

PHP:

```
$image = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/file.png");
```

Ruby:

```
require 'net/http'
image = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://www.example.com/file.png")).body
```

Comment: Awesome, you are amazing. Thank you VERRYYY much.

Answer (score 3):

For http/https/ftp you can use OpenURI module:

```
require "open-uri"
image = open("http://www.example.com/file.png").read
```